# preg match check if present class

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code in my PHP page:

```
$regex = '/<img.*?>/';
```

I need that `preg_match` replace only images that don't have `class="nopopup"`

What is the correct regular expression?

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate ? This question doesn't ask _HOW TO USE A DOM IN PHP_ does it ?? It asks for a  _**REGEX**_ , not a DOM  parsing usage question !!

Comment: Who marked this as a duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution that avoids complicated regular expressions. Rather, keep your simple regex that looks for image elements, and use `preg_replace_callback`. For each match, this function will call a function defined by you and passes it that match. Then, you use a simple regular expression that scans the match for the string `class="nopopup"`. It it's there, perform the replacement. If it's not there, you just return the original string.